# what is the best way to pass arguments to thread in C windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, arguments

Hi
I have a thread that uses couple of variables.
variables are determined in runtime from argv[].

My options as i see them:

1. make the variables global so the threads can use them (don't need to protect them since the thread doesn't change them). i'm reluctant to use this since global variables are not so good
2. create a struct to hold the variables and pass it to the thread. the varibales are not really related so it would be a "forced" struct with no meaning other than argument for the thread. also, more complicated than option 1

Are there other options ? Which one is considered better ?

Thanks !

Comment: There's a reason you're allowed to pass a parameter to the thread -- use it. Don't use globals unless you have absolutely no other choice.

Comment: It's dogma that says not to use globals here. If the parameters are constant for the processes lifetime then what's wrong with globals? I can't write this app am answer because the dogmatists will vote it down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it would be a "forced" struct with no meaning other than argument for the thread

That sounds like a pretty good use for a struct.  The data members are all related by virtue of the fact that they all need to be passed to the thread.

It's not really more complicated than the first option (unless one considers defining a struct and copying a few variables to be complicated).  It's a little more code, sure, but it should also make it easier to look at the code and see exactly what data is given to the threads.

Comment: +1. Also, you'd regret using global variables the day you (or someone else) decide that the threads _need_ to modify the variables, but forget to take into account that the variables are shared between the threads...

Answer (score 0):

There's little real question that the second is the right way to do. Globals become *particularly* problematic with multithreading. If the change at all during execution, they become even problematic, as you'll need some sort of mutex (or whatever) to protect them as they're being modified. They can easily become a bottleneck as everything serializes on using those globals.

I'd also mention that if the parameters for a thread truly are completely unrelated, I have to wonder what your threads are doing, and (particularly) whether the design might not need some work. There should be a logical relationship for the simple reason that a what a thread does should itself be logical -- if the inputs are really unrelated, then operations on them should probably be separate as well.